# How to add a new class into a JAR File?

Tags: java, jar

How do I add a new class into the jar file ? I followed the example in here 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

by entering the command "jar uf test.jar main_folder/folder1/test_class1.class" and it says "no such file or directory". Inside the jar file consist of the folderName called main_folder and inside that, it have another folder called folder1. I would like to add in another class file into that subfolder but everytime I entered the command it says no such file or directory. So may I know why or what did i missed?

My test_class1.class file is inside the same folder with the test.jar file. Both of them are in the TestJar folder that I had named.

```
TestJar (folder)
        ------- test_class1.class
        ------- test.jar
```

Thank you.

Comment: If the Class you are adding is related to the others and called correctly in your application, just use WINZIP and copy the file there. I have doing that for yonks. jar file is just an archive that can be opened using winzip. Copy without extracting the archive.

Comment: but then if i were to use winzip, do i need to recompile the whole thing into a jar file again in order for the jar file to function? and thank you for the prompt reply =) I appreciate it

Comment: No you can copy without extracting.

Comment: @AuroraBlaze: A .jar file is literally just a .zip file with a different extension, and with files arranged in certain folders inside it.  (Oh, and there's a manifest.  But that just tells Java how to run it. You shouldn't have to care about that in most cases.)

Comment: okay, please let me try it. I am currently downloading the winzip =)

Comment: @cHao, May I know if it will effect anything to the java or something as I will be calling the jar's class file/methods inside eclipse (java)

Comment: @Stanley I dont seem to be able to open the jar file using winzip

Comment: Your code should be able to find the class without you having to do anything else (as long as you put the class file in the right place).  If Eclipse is actually looking in the jar for stuff, it'll see the class too.

Comment: If you got Winrar it will be much easier. Just Open winrar>>File>>open archive then navigate into the jar you want to Open ....just drag and drop the class file in the location you want it to go.

Comment: Easiest way i've found to make WinZip work with .jar files is to rename them to change the extension to .zip.  Like i said, jars are literally just zip files with a particular directory structure inside.

Comment: @AuroraBlaze Glad you could get something out of it. :) Welcome